# Variant characters in PDO statement doesn't work in IE9

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm using PHP 5.4.31 and MySQL version 5.5.39-MariaDB. My database is in utf8_general_ci collation and some of my fields contain latin variants like á and é.

I am using the mysql:charset=utf8 directly in my PDO statement which works fine in Chrome and FireFox (on PC, Mac and tablet). But doesn't work in IE9.

If I use a URL such as "url_of_page.php?firstName=Joe&lastName=González" IE9 cannot find the record.

```
// get variables from URL
$fName = $_GET["firstName"] ;
$lName = $_GET["lastName"] ;

try {
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:charset=utf8;host=$hostname;dbname=databaseName", $username, $password);

/*** set the error reporting attribute ***/
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

/*** The SQL SELECT statement ***/
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE FirstName = :firstName AND LastName = :lastName");

/*** bind the paramaters ***/
$stmt->bindParam(':firstName', $fName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':lastName', $lName, PDO::PARAM_STR);

/*** execute the prepared statement ***/
$stmt->execute();

/*** fetch the results ***/
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach($result as $row) {
```

I've also tried using $stmt->execute("set names utf8"); which makes no difference. Don't understand why this is a browser issue. Any idea why IE is having problems?

Comment: are you sure those chars came through cleanly in $_GET? do they show up properly if you do `echo $fName`?

Comment: I see that it is not. When I turn on Auto-select in the IE Encoding menu it displays correctly. But then as soon as I refresh the page the variant displays incorrect (little square box). I have noticed that when I mouse over a URL in IE the variants don't appear in the URL (that is displayed at the bottom of the browser), but then variant characters are displayed within the URL once I actual go to the page. Variant characters are displaying when just pulled from DB, but not within the $_GET.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I had not used urlencode when assigning my URL variables and my URL was not in a valid ASCII format. After using urlencode my correct URL was something like:

url_of_page.php?firstName=Joe&lastName=Gonz%C3%A1lez

instead of

url_of_page.php?firstName=Joe&lastName=González